# How to decode a JSON Dictionary?

Tags: json, swift, decode

I am able to decode straight forward json responses but as the JSON gets more nested, I'm struggling.

To decode JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "username": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "fullName": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "isInActivity": true,
    "activeEventId": "string",
    "initials": "string"
  }
]
```

My struct is:

```
struct FriendsStruct: Decodable, Hashable {
    var initials: String
    var username: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var fullName: String
    var email: String
    var isInActivity: Bool
    var activeEventId: String
    var id: String
}
```

And to decode:

```
func getFriends(token: String, force: Bool) async throws -> Int {
    var request = EndPoints().getFriendsEndPoint(force: force)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
    guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {return httpResponse?.statusCode ?? 0}
    let decodedFriends = try JSONDecoder().decode([FriendsStruct].self, from: data)
    self.updateCoreDataFriendsRecords(friendsData: decodedFriends)
    return httpResponse?.statusCode ?? 1000
}
```

Can someone advise as to how I might decode with the same approach but with a nested response such as:

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "memberId": "string",
      "memberName": "string",
      "memberUsername": "string",
      "memberType": 0,
      "isMyFriend": true,
      "initials": "string"
    }
  ],
  "name": "string",
  "owner": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "groupType": 0,
  "expiryDate": "2023-02-06T20:00:03.834Z",
  "readOnly": true,
  "isDeleted": true,
  "approvalRequired": true,
  "joinWithCode": true,
  "numberOfMembers": 0,
  "groupAssociation": 0,
  "id": "string",
  "etag": "string"
}
```

Comment: as the JSON would produce nested objects in JavaScript, I would try nested structs (here: a field of a type `Member` struct inside the `FriendsStruct`)

Comment: You could paste your json here: https://app.quicktype.io/ and it will generate the corresponding code for you.

Comment: Thanks koen, that's a really cool tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two structs: a `Member` struct with properties in the JSON (as you did for the simple example) and an outer level struct for the base data that includes a property which is an array of `Member`. For example:

```
struct Member: Decodable {
   let memberId: String
   let memberName: String
   let memberUsername: String
   let memberType: Int
   let isMyFriend: Bool
   let initials: String
}

struct Group: Decodable {
   let members: [Member]
   let name: String
   let owner: String
   let description: String
   let groupType: Int
   let expiryDate: String
   let readOnly: Bool
   let isDeleted: Bool
   let approvalRequired: Bool
   let joinWithCode: Bool
   let numberOfMembers: Int
   let groupAssociation: Int
   let id: String
   let etag: String
   
}
```

This is treating the data exactly as it is in the JSON.  You'd probably want to go further and use a CodingKeys enum to map some of the json fields onto more suitable property names, and maybe, depending on needs, use a `Date` for the expiry date and decode the date string.

**EDIT**

As a follow up I mentioned the next step might be decoding the `expiryDate` field into a `Date` property.  The answer passed over this as it appeared to be an `.iso8601` date format, in which case all that is required is to set the date decoding strategy on the decoder accordingly:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601)
let group = decoder.decode(Group.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)  // force unwrapping for brevity.  Don't ;-)
```

However this won't work as the date field contains fractional seconds and Swift's decoder only supports whole seconds.  This makes it a bit more interesting :-) as you'll need to define a custom decoder:

```
extension DateFormatter {
   static let iso8601WithFractionalSeconds: DateFormatter = {
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
      formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
      formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
      return formatter
   }()
}
```

This then lets you decoder the `expiryDate` string to a `Date` within the decoder.  Change the expiry date field to a `Date` and decode as below.

```
struct Group: Decodable {
   //...
   let expiryDate: Date
   //...
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601WithFractionalSeconds)
let group = try! decoder.decode(Group.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Thanks flanker, awesome. Just what I needed to understand the best approach.

Comment: Don't escape the `Z`. There is no guarantee that the date string timezone will always be UTC. Btw `iso8601WithSeconds` is misleading should be `iso8601WithFractionalSeconds`. Last but not least you should set the `locale` before setting the `dateFormat`

Comment: **"Once you've set "en_US_POSIX" as the locale of the date formatter, you can then set the date format string and the date formatter will behave consistently for all users"**  [Technical Q&A QA1480
NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus.  Wasn't aware of the ordering issue referenced in the tech note - very helpful.  The escaping and naming were just me being careless; and I've no idea why I escaped the Z!